# Passing data from Angular to MVC controller deserialize an empty Viewmodel

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing some maintenance on an Angular project,
I got a strange behavior when passing an object from controller to the service...for simplicity I've reduced the read payload to just a field

Here's the Angular controller

```
  $scope.createNorm = function () {

    var norma = {};
    norma.IdType = -1;

    createDialog({
        title: "Creazione di una nuova norma",
        template: NormeService.dialogTemplate,
        okLabel: "Salva",
        controller: ["$scope", "NormeService", function ($scope, NormeService) {

            $scope.aziende = [];
            $scope.tipoNorme = [];

            var init = function () {

                NormeService.getCompanyList().then(function (response) {
                    var arr = response.data.Items || [];
                    var aziende = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        aziende.push({
                            Text: arr[i].Value,
                            Value: arr[i].Id
                        });
                    }
                    $scope.aziende = aziende;
                });

                NormeService.getNormTypesList().then(function (response) {

                    var arr = response.data || [];
                    var tipoNorme = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        tipoNorme.push({
                            Text: arr[i].NAME,
                            Value: arr[i].ID
                        });
                    }

                    console.log(tipoNorme);
                    $scope.tipoNorme = tipoNorme;
                });

            };
            init();

            $scope.norma = angular.copy(norma);
            $scope.value = $scope.norma;
        }]
    }).then(function (result) {
        $scope.save(result);
    }, function () { });
};
```

The Angular service

```
 save: function (data) {

            $http.post(baseUrl + "/save-norm2", { Norm:data});
        },
```

The service data template

```
  dialogTemplate: [
            '<advancedselect options="tipoNorme" label="Tipo norma" ng-model="norma.IdType" type="text" ng-required="false" form-model="frm" />', /*ng - required="true"*/
```

The MVC Viewmodel

```
public class TempViewModel
{
 public int IdType { get; set; }
}
```

and the MVC Controller

```
   [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("save-norm2")]
    public IHttpActionResult SaveNorm(TempViewModel Norm)
    {
        return Ok(true);
    }
```

I've got the value corrected filled on the browser part as you can see from the screenshot.

[image]

When it reaches the Controller on the MVC part it gots 0 as IdType

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so this can be the issue?? but till the browser call everything is filled..I see in chrome IdType valorized

Comment: The `.then` method *returns a new promise* which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the `successCallback`, `errorCallback` (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using [promise chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues)). The `$.all` method returns a single promise from an array or hash of promises. For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api).

Comment: In general, when the code chains promises, there should be return statements. When a `.then` method has either `successCallback` or `errorCallback` that omits a return statement, the promise resolves with undefined and doesn't wait for the previous promise. I see no [return statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).